# How to stop a VBScript that was started in a batch program?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wsh

So I am making a game in batch programming and I decided to add some theme music to the title menu screen. The way I added the music was by using `WScript` and a VBScript to play a mp3 file.

The only problem is that once it starts it plays in the background and not through the batch file, therefore, once you start the game the theme music continues to play. I have used this script for simple little sounds that end quickly so it's never been an issue before.

So my question is, is it possible to stop the script from within the batch file instead of having to do the old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> method?

Here is my in text script:

```batch
set music=ThemeMusic.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
echo Sound.URL = "%music%"
echo Sound.Controls.play
echo Do While Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo WScript.Sleep 100
echo Loop
echo WScript.Sleep (Int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /max sound.vbs
```

and here is the code for the separate VBScript that is opened through the batch file:

```vb
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Sound.URL = "ThemeMusic.mp3"
Sound.Controls.play
Do While Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
WScript.Sleep (Int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
```

Comment: We can already see your code creating the Vbscript. No need to post it again. If you want to kill a program use TASKKILL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `TASKKILL /IM wscript.exe`. However, keep in mind that this will end all VBScript processes.

In the future, use `TASKKILL /?` in the console for various other methods. It will display the following:

```
TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
         { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/T] [/F]

Description:
    This tool is used to terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name.

Parameter List:
    /S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U    [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which the
                           command should execute.

    /P    [password]       Specifies the password for the given user
                           context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    /FI   filter           Applies a filter to select a set of tasks.
                           Allows "*" to be used. ex. imagename eq acme*

    /PID  processid        Specifies the PID of the process to be terminated.
                           Use TaskList to get the PID.

    /IM   imagename        Specifies the image name of the process
                           to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used
                           to specify all tasks or image names.

    /T                     Terminates the specified process and any
                           child processes which were started by it.

    /F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).

    /?                     Displays this help message.

Filters:
    Filter Name   Valid Operators           Valid Value(s)
    -----------   ---------------           -------------------------
    STATUS        eq, ne                    RUNNING |
                                            NOT RESPONDING | UNKNOWN
    IMAGENAME     eq, ne                    Image name
    PID           eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    PID value
    SESSION       eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    Session number.
    CPUTIME       eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    CPU time in the format
                                            of hh:mm:ss.
                                            hh - hours,
                                            mm - minutes, ss - seconds
    MEMUSAGE      eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    Memory usage in KB
    USERNAME      eq, ne                    User name in [domain\]user
                                            format
    MODULES       eq, ne                    DLL name
    SERVICES      eq, ne                    Service name
    WINDOWTITLE   eq, ne                    Window title

    NOTE
    ----
    1) Wildcard '*' for /IM switch is accepted only when a filter is applied.
    2) Termination of remote processes will always be done forcefully (/F).
    3) "WINDOWTITLE" and "STATUS" filters are not considered when a remote
       machine is specified.

Examples:
    TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKILL /PID 1230 /PID 1241 /PID 1253 /T
    TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe /T
    TASKKILL /F /FI "PID ge 1000" /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne untitle*"
    TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKILL /S system /U domain\username /FI "USERNAME ne NT*" /IM *
    TASKKILL /S system /U username /P password /FI "IMAGENAME eq note*"
```

Comment: Is it possible to end a specific vbs script this way or does it have to end all vbs scripts?

Comment: Only if the VBScript has a window open with a unique title.

Comment: TASKKILL /IM wscript.exe  - don't work in msta children streems for me.

Answer (score 2):

I always use this.

```
taskkill /F /IM wscript.exe /T
```